# How to show the highest Configurable Product price in magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

How to show the highest Configurable Product price in Magento 2.

At the basis, Magento shows the lowest price ( from the simple product ) for configurable products.

Is there a way to display the highest price for all configurable products?

Hope someone can help me out!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please check solution here , https://webkul.com/blog/get-price-range-configurable-product-magento-2/

Comment: Good answer. Although just to add to this. This is display only. This will not apply to filtering.